# 5.1 audio on YouTube videos?

Tags: audio, youtube

[How do I get Stereo + 5.1 for YouTube videos?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16558/how-do-i-get-stereo-5-1-for-youtube-videos)

It has been a long time since somebody made a question about this topic on this forum and lots of stuff have changed since then. So does YouTube support 5.1 audio now, in 2021?

Comment: Don't create a new question if there's an older one which is exactly the same. You have the possibility to add answers if you find out anything new (in this case there is no news on 5.1 sound) or with higher reputation add comments. But the one thing you should not do is creating the same question again. We'll close the question as duplicate, you'll see an automatic comment inserted below mine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get Stereo + 5.1 for YouTube videos?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16558/how-do-i-get-stereo-5-1-for-youtube-videos)

Comment: its over 5 years old, youtube isnt flash anymore

Comment: I meant, there is no news from YouTube's side. They supported upload of 5.1 back then and still support it today. If you download the audio with youtube-dl you can get a 5.1 track (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRjbuXjNwrk, try the m4a_dash 48000Hz format). Browser/app playback seems to work only under very specific hardware/software combinations if at all, many people failed to get this working.

Comment: On closer inspection, the answers on the linked questions are all not very useful. Still, it'll mess up the site if people repost existing questions. Follow the old one and wait until somebody answers or do your own research & experiments and post your answer. In case you get stuck in the middle you can ask a new detailed question on this topic, e.g. when you have produced a proper 5.1 audio track and upload it with the correct video codec to YouTube and it's still not working, then you can come back and create a question about why it didn't work in your case.

Comment: good idea.......

Comment: seems like 5.1 videos could be downloaded with youtube-dl, meaning that 5.1 is supported on stuff like TV systems